# MongoDB PHP driver: Query for Distinct records with Limit and Skip

Tags: php, mongodb

I saw previous questions on this. But none of them are based on latest driver.

So far my code is like below:

```
$mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$regex1 = new MongoDB\BSON\Regex("^[A-z]","i");
$filter = ['searchcontent.name' => $regex1];
$options = [
   'limit' => 50,
   'skip' => 0
];

$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$rows = $mongo->executeQuery('webdb.search', $query);

foreach($rows as $r){    
    echo "<br/>".$r->searchcontent->name."<br/>";
}
```

This code is returning duplicates as I have duplicates in my database. I want to implement distinct on this. I read official documentation, but not able to find anything.

I tried like this:

```
$options = [
   'limit' => 50,
   'skip' => 0,
'distinct'=>'searchcontent.name'
];
```

But it did not work for me. Please help.

**Edit:**

[PHP official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-command.php) have a distinct example with executeCommand().

But the problem is I am not able to use limit and skip with this code.

**Summary:**

I want a query which will contain `limit`,`skip` and `distinct`.

A solution with `executeCommand()` or with `executeQuery()` or anything else will work for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use aggregation pipeline and use `$group` for distinct records.

```
$mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$regex1 = new MongoDB\BSON\Regex("^[A-z]","i");

$pipeline = [
    [ '$match' => ['searchcontent.name' => $regex1] ],
    [ '$group' => ['_id' => '$searchcontent.name'] ],
    [ '$limit' => 50 ],
    [ '$skip' => 10 ],
];

$aggregate = new \MongoDB\Driver\Command([
   'aggregate' => 'search', 
   'pipeline' => $pipeline
]);

$cursor = $mongo->executeCommand('webdb', $aggregate);

foreach($cursor as $key => $document) {
    var_dump($document);
}
```

Alternatively, you should install the library through [composer](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/tutorial/install-php-library/) which provides similar syntax as old api.

```
$collection = (new MongoDB\Client)->webdb->search;

$cursor = $collection->aggregate([
    [ '$match' => ['searchcontent.name' => $regex1] ],
    [ '$group' => ['_id' => '$searchcontent.name'] ],
    [ '$limit' => 50 ],
    [ '$skip' => 10 ],
]);

foreach($cursor as $key => $document) {
    var_dump($document);
}
```